# Taking screenshot of the current screen in BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry

Is it possible to take a screenshot of the current screen in a BlackBerry Application? I have a button in my screen, when I click the button I want to send an email with the screenshot of the current screen.

Comment: http://appworld.blackberry.com/webstore/content/3301

Comment: @MithunSasidharan - OP wants to do this from code, not by running another app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following method to get a screenshot of the displayed screen

```
public static Bitmap getScreenShot() {
    // get the current screen .
    Bitmap bitmap;
    bitmap = new Bitmap(Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight());
    Display.screenshot(bitmap);
    // return the screen shot
    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: I have used same code. I am able to capture screenshot in non-touch devices, but in touch devices it returns me blank bitmap image. Do you know why?

Answer (score 3):

You can take a screenshot by calling [`Display.screenshot(aBitmap)`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/Display.html#screenshot%28net.rim.device.api.system.Bitmap%29), passing a Bitmap of the right size. There's also a version of the method that can take a screenshot of a part of the screen.

Comment: how to save this bitmap in sd card ?

Comment: @RezJohn - There's sample code [here](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Capture-and-save-a-screen-shot/ta-p/445212)